# MSBuild properties empty for .NETStandard lib project

Tags: c#, msbuild, .net-standard

When I try to use msbuild properties like `$(TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory)` or `$(SDKToolsPath)` in a custom build target for a .NETStandard libary, these properties are empty/not defined. Using the exact same build target for a .NET 4.6.2 Assembly works fine however. Are there .targets files I need to manually include for .NETStandard or what else could I be missing?

Importing `$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props` does not help. I am using Visual Studio 2017 Community.

*.csproj for .NETStandard lib:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netstandard1.4</TargetFramework>
        <RootNamespace>MyNamespace</RootNamespace>
        <AllowUnsafeBlocks>True</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <!--
    ItemGroups for files and references
    -->
    <Target Name="PropsTest" BeforeTargets="CoreCompile">
        <!-- Prints: "Path: " -->
        <Message Text="Path: $(TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory)" Importance="high" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

*.csproj for .NET 4.6.2 app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
    <PropertyGroup>
        <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
        <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
        <ProjectGuid>{73E77BB7-D3F9-4797-B62D-24666D1132EF}</ProjectGuid>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <RootNamespace>SamplesConsole</RootNamespace>
        <AssemblyName>SamplesConsole</AssemblyName>
        <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
        <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
        <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
        <TargetFrameworkProfile />
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
        <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
        <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
        <DebugType>full</DebugType>
        <Optimize>false</Optimize>
        <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
        <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
        <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
        <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
        <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
        <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
        <Optimize>true</Optimize>
        <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
        <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
        <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
        <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <!--
    ItemGroups for files and references
    -->
    <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
    <Target Name="PropsTest" BeforeTargets="CoreCompile">
        <!-- Prints: "Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\" -->
        <Message Text="Path: $(TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory)" Importance="high" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: .NETStandard projects are supposed to be compatible with platform targets like iOS, Android, Linux, etc.  It makes no sense whatsoever to want to do anything with the Windows SDK.  Avoid XY questions.

Comment: Specifically I want to use ildasm/ilasm. Is there a another way to use them then? The functionality should be available on the other platforms, no? Also, what do you mean with "Avoid XY questions"?

Comment: Ok, I now know what a XY question is (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What an undescriptive name... Should I delete this question or leave it for others who try the same (stupid) approach as me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the .NET 4.6.2 Library the TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory property is set by Microsoft.NETFramework.CurrentVersion.props.

It's set with either $(SDK35ToolsPath) or $(SDK40ToolsPath).

SDK40ToolsPath property is available in a .NET Standard Library build even though TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory is not.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed!